# Need to create a column name which displays current month end

Tags: sql, database, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, create-table

I have a requirement to create a column name in snowflake such that it displays the current month end date. It should change dynamically every month.

Expected table structure.

```
Tablename:- sample
Column names :- 
1.Name - Varchar field
2.2023-01-31 (Should be Current monthend) - Integer field.
```

When I do a `select * from sample` NEXT month , the column names should be as below :

| Name | 2023-02-29 |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 15876 |
| B3 | 8976 |

I have tried something like this using identifier, and it is throwing the below error in the create table statement.

> "Unexpected '('.syntax error line 5 at position 0 unexpected ')'.

```
Set NEW123=(to_varchar(Current_Date(),'YYYY-MM-DD');

CREATE TABLE SAMPLE
(
IDENTIFIER($NEW123) INTEGER
);
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output ?

Comment: Also, update your question to show what you’ve tried - obviously this would need to be a view

Comment: It's not possible to create a table (or view) with dynamic column names. The only way to (possibly) get this to work is to create a table function that dynamically creates a view with the column names you want and then call this function in your SELECT e.g. SELECT * FROM TABLE(your_custom_function);

Comment: As I m a beginner to snowflake , I m not aware of how to create views with the columnnames that changes dynamically. Any sample commands or syntax is highly helpful

Comment: You probably need to start by learning about user-defined table functions (UDTFs) and this documentation is a good place to begin: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/udf-overview. However, if you are a beginner at Snowflake then this seems to be a pretty complicated piece of functionality that you are trying to build. You probably need to think about whether you really need it

Comment: Column names should not be variable. There's definitely a problem with the design of your database although without more information about the specific requirements it's hard to say what the solution should be. Rather than looking for a way to achieve these dynamic column names you should be looking for a way to design the database so that it doesn't need them.

Answer (score 0):

so the SQL you wish the results to be would be the equivalent of:

```
create table "SAMPLE" (name text, "2023-02-29" number);
```

the table name needs to be in quotes because `sample` is a reserved word.

using LAST_DAY we can get the month end:

```
select current_date() as cd
    ,LAST_DAY(cd, 'month') as end_date;
```

| CD | END_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-12 | 2024-01-31 |

so now we just need to build the SQL we want:

```
select current_date() as cd
    ,LAST_DAY(cd, 'month') as end_date
    ,'create table "SAMPLE" (name text, "'|| LAST_DAY(cd, 'month')::text ||'" number)' as sql;
```

| CD | END_DATE | SQL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-12 | 2024-01-31 | create table "SAMPLE" (name text, "2024-01-31" number) |

lovely, lovely, now lets run that via [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate)

```
DECLARE
    sql text;
BEGIN
    sql := 'create table "SAMPLE" (name text, "'|| LAST_DAY(current_date(), 'month')::text ||'" number)';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql;
END;
```

```
select * from "SAMPLE";
```

[image]